# Too much memory being used on low intensity work. c++

Tags: c++, memory

Keep in mind I've only been using CPP for around a week so the code is not very good. I wrote this to solve the problem 1362A on CodeForces. Long story short, the code works fine except for the fact that it says the memory used is 262100 KB. I've looked over it multiple times but can't find anything that would cause lots of memory to be used.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
using namespace std;

uint64_t makeq(uint64_t x, uint64_t y)
{
    uint64_t q;
    if (x >= y)
    {

        q = x / y;
    }
    else
    {

        q = y / x;
    }
    return q;
}

bool check(uint64_t x, uint64_t y, uint64_t q)
{
    if (x >= y)
    {
        if (x % y != 0)
        {
            cout << -1 << "\n";
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (y % x != 0)
        {

            cout << -1 << "\n";
            return false;
        }
    }
    //checking float
    if (q > 8 && q % 8 != 0)
    {
        cout << -1 << "\n";
        return false;
    }
    if (q == 1)
    {
        cout << 0 << "\n";
        return false;
    }
    if (q % 2 != 0)
    {
        cout << -1 << "\n";
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
int main()
{
    uint64_t n, x, y, q, c;
    cin >> n;
    while (n--)
    {
        c = 0;
        cin >> x >> y;
        q = makeq(x, y);
        if (check(x, y, q) == false)
        {
            continue;
        }
        while (q > 1)
        {

            if (q >= 8 && q % 8 == 0)
            {
                q /= 8;

                c += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                if (q >= 4 && q % 4 == 0)
                {
                    q /= 4;
                    c += 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    q /= 2;
                    c += 1;
                }
            }
        }
        cout << c << endl
            << flush;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**

Comment: Just a quick note: endl actually flushes the output buffer, so no need for <<endl<<flush, and flushing isn't even required in most cases, so it could either be <<"\n" or <<endl

Comment: I think the site is wrong.

Comment: When a process is taking a lot of memory, the best thing to do is to take a dump and investigate that: which data are taking up all that memory?

Comment: maybe the binary itself?

Comment: Make sure you’re testing optimized release build.

Comment: Horrible naming. You expect people on SO go to that web site, search the problem themselves, and then come back here and answer your question? I recommend the [ask] page.

Comment: @Soonts It's a competitive coding site, they have no control over the compiler. Most of them are also still stuck on C++14.

Comment: On a lark, I went to the site; searching for 1362A gives **0** results. I had to manually trawl the problem list.

Comment: Try evaluating this expression:  `uint64_t  z = makeq(5,0);`.

Comment: You run it on the site? Or on your computer? In my computer the memory used is 5496Kb

Comment: I don't see anything in the code that uses anything but fixed numbers of stack frames. Memory is not your issue